# Android TV Emulator: Wrong Orientation

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-tv

When I create a new Android TV virtual device from the AVD Manager and launch it in the emulator the orientation is all wrong (see image). How do I get it to start in landscape?

[Image: Android TV Emulator - Wrong Orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJOvB.png)

The **config.ini** for the device:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=Android_TV_1080p_API_23
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Android TV (1080p) API 23
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=no
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=no
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.dPad=yes
hw.device.hash2=MD5:f26df701fd74415b9a435e3e607b5d8a
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Android TV (1080p)
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.initialOrientation=landscape
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.keyboard.lid=yes
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=no
hw.sensors.proximity=no
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-23\android-tv\x86\
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=auto
sdcard.path=C:\Users\Emil\.android\avd\Android_TV_1080p_API_23.avd\sdcard.img
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=1920x1080
skin.path=1920x1080
snapshot.present=no
tag.display=Android TV
tag.id=android-tv
vm.heapSize=128
```

Comment: I've been having this problem as well but have not found a solution.

Comment: try with my answer given below for TV landscape emulator.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the TV emulator, it is in portrait mode by default.
To change the orientation to landscape, press numpad 9 key that is on right hand side of keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is possible to rotate it with seven or nine on the numpad, but I was hoping I could make it start in landscape mode, because then I can use auto-scale to make it fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Change `hw.initialOrientation` to `portrait`, mine works with this configuration.

I guess the emulator sees 1920*1080 as default portrait, so it becomes 1080*1920 in landscape mode (which is actually portrait).

If you're creating AVD using Android Studio, you should select the 4th one, instead of 3rd one. It gives you a nice device frame and boots with a landscape screen.

[image: Select AVD]